# Why is the image background purple

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-imageview

I'm trying to display [this transparent image](http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/4908_obj_big.gif?id=2) in a ImageView.

I download and set the image with this class:

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private String TAG = "DownloadImageTask";
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the background gets purple. Why does it get purple and how do I solve this?

Comment: Check if you have background color defined for your ImageView in your XML layout. What happens to other controls in your view? If they are also getting the same color, then it could be view background.

Comment: @Raghu i have not set a color. Even if i set a color it is alway purple. Magenta i believe it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solution, but more like a fix.

I created a mutable bitmap and changed the colors.

```
    Bitmap copy = result.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int [] allpixels = new int [ copy.getHeight()*copy.getWidth()];
    copy.getPixels(allpixels, 0, copy.getWidth(), 0, 0, copy.getWidth(), copy.getHeight());
    for(int i =0; i < copy.getHeight() * copy.getWidth(); i++)
    {
        if( allpixels[i] == Color.MAGENTA)
        {
            allpixels[i] = Color.TRANSPARENT;
        }
    }
    copy.setPixels(allpixels, 0, copy.getWidth(), 0, 0, copy.getWidth(), copy.getHeight());

    bmImage.setImageBitmap(copy);
```